# border/edge operations on numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Suppose I have a 3D numpy array of nonzero values and `"background" = 0`. As an example I will take a sphere of random values:

```
array = np.random.randint(1, 5, size = (100,100,100))
z,y,x = np.ogrid[-50:50, -50:50, -50:50]
mask = x**2 + y**2 + z**2<= 20**2
array[np.invert(mask)] = 0
```

First, I would like to find the "border voxels" (all nonzero values that have a zero within their `3x3x3` neigbourhood). Second, I would like to replace all border voxels with the mean of their nonzero neighbours. So far I tried to use scipy's generic filter in the following way:

Function to apply at each element:

```
def borderCheck(values):
    #check if the footprint center is on a nonzero value
    if values[13] != 0:
        #replace border voxels with the mean of nonzero neighbours
        if 0 in values:
            return np.sum(values)/np.count_nonzero(values)
        else:
            return values[13]
    else:
        return 0
```

Generic filter:

```
from scipy import ndimage
result = ndimage.generic_filter(array, borderCheck, footprint = np.ones((3,3,3)))
```

Is this a proper way to handle this problem? I feel that I am trying to reinvent the wheel here and that there must be a shorter, nicer way to achieve the result. Are there any other suitable (numpy, scipy ) functions that I can use?

**EDIT**

I messed one thing up: I would like to replace all border voxels with the mean of their nonzero **AND non-border** neighbours. For this, I tried to clean up the `neighbours` from ali_m's code (2D case):

```
#for each neighbour voxel, check whether it also appears in the border/edges
non_border_neighbours = []
for each in neighbours:
    non_border_neighbours.append([i for i in each if nonzero_idx[i] not in edge_idx])
```

Now I can't figure out why `non_border_neighbours` comes back empty?

Furthermore, correct me if I am wrong but doesn't `tree.query_ball_point` with radius 1 adress only the 6 next neighbours (euclidean distance 1)? Should I set `sqrt(3)` (3D case) as radius to get the 26-neighbourhood?

Comment: 1) To get the *non-border neighbours* you could  take the bitwise difference between the mask after eroding it once vs twice, e.g. `candidate_neighbours = erode ^ erode2`. I think your listcomp probably fails because `in edge_idx` will return a boolean array rather than a scalar, and arrays are "truthy".

Comment: 2) I'm not using euclidean distance anywhere - the `p=np.inf` in `query_ball_point` means to use the infinity (a.k.a. max) norm, so `p=np.inf, r=1` means to find all points that are *at most one pixel/voxel from the query point in any direction*. In 2D space this could be anything up to a 3x3 grid for a non-border pixel, in 3D space it could be 3x3x3 etc. You can check the sizes of the index arrays returned by `query_ball_point` to confirm this.

Comment: I was checking the example in the reference guide for `query_ball_point` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point). My mistake was keeping the default parameters (not infinity norm), so thanks again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's best to start out with the 2D case first, since it can be visualized much more easily:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

A = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(100, 100)).astype(np.double)
y, x = np.ogrid[-50:50, -50:50]
mask = x**2 + y**2 <= 30**2
A[~mask] = 0
```

To find the edge pixels you could perform binary erosion on your mask, then XOR the result with your mask

```
# rank 2 structure with full connectivity
struct = ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2, 2)
erode = ndimage.binary_erosion(mask, struct)
edges = mask ^ erode
```

One approach to find the nearest non-zero neighbours of each edge pixel would be to use a [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0O5m.png):

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# the indices of the non-zero locations and their corresponding values
nonzero_idx = np.vstack(np.where(mask)).T
nonzero_vals = A[mask]

# build a k-D tree
tree = cKDTree(nonzero_idx)

# use it to find the indices of all non-zero values that are at most 1 pixel
# away from each edge pixel
edge_idx = np.vstack(np.where(edges)).T
neighbours = tree.query_ball_point(edge_idx, r=1, p=np.inf)

# take the average value for each set of neighbours
new_vals = np.hstack(np.mean(nonzero_vals[n]) for n in neighbours)

# use these to replace the values of the edge pixels
A_new = A.astype(np.double, copy=True)
A_new[edges] = new_vals
```

Some visualisation:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)
norm = plt.Normalize(0, A.max())
ax[0].imshow(A, norm=norm)
ax[0].set_title('Original', fontsize='x-large')
ax[1].imshow(edges)
ax[1].set_title('Edges', fontsize='x-large')
ax[2].imshow(A_new, norm=norm)
ax[2].set_title('Averaged', fontsize='x-large')
for aa in ax:
    aa.set_axis_off()
ax[0].set_xlim(20, 50)
ax[0].set_ylim(50, 80)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

This approach will also generalize to the 3D case:

```
B = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(100, 100, 100)).astype(np.double)
z, y, x = np.ogrid[-50:50, -50:50, -50:50]
mask = x**2 + y**2 + z**2 <= 20**2
B[~mask] = 0

struct = ndimage.generate_binary_structure(3, 3)
erode = ndimage.binary_erosion(mask, struct)
edges = mask ^ erode

nonzero_idx = np.vstack(np.where(mask)).T
nonzero_vals = B[mask]

tree = cKDTree(nonzero_idx)

edge_idx = np.vstack(np.where(edges)).T
neighbours = tree.query_ball_point(edge_idx, r=1, p=np.inf)

new_vals = np.hstack(np.mean(nonzero_vals[n]) for n in neighbours)

B_new = B.astype(np.double, copy=True)
B_new[edges] = new_vals
```

Test against your version:

```
def borderCheck(values):
    #check if the footprint center is on a nonzero value
    if values[13] != 0:
        #replace border voxels with the mean of nonzero neighbours
        if 0 in values:
            return np.sum(values)/np.count_nonzero(values)
        else:
            return values[13]
    else:
        return 0

result = ndimage.generic_filter(B, borderCheck, footprint=np.ones((3, 3, 3)))

print(np.allclose(B_new, result))
# True
```

I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way to do it, but it will still be significantly faster than using `generic_filter`.

---

### Update

The performance could be further improved by reducing the number of points that are considered as candidate neighbours of the edge pixels/voxels:

```
# ...

# the edge pixels/voxels plus their immediate non-zero neighbours
erode2 = ndimage.binary_erosion(erode, struct)
candidate_neighbours = mask ^ erode2

nonzero_idx = np.vstack(np.where(candidate_neighbours)).T
nonzero_vals = B[candidate_neighbours]

# ...
```

Comment: Thank's for the detailed answer! I have never used a k-D tree before and I think it is also suitable for some other stuff I am working on.

Comment: Great! See my update for another suggestion that might help to speed things up, although if performance is really important to you then the fastest method is always going to be implementing your own filter in C/Cython etc.

Comment: Actually I have another issue concerning that task (see my update in the question). Maybe you can give me a hint with that...