# Draw contour around binary mask image in Python

Tags: python, contour, imshow

I have a binary mask of the Antarctic ice sheet with pixels 0 = no ice sheet and 1 = ice sheet. How can I create a contour around the ice sheet pixels so that it creates an edge around the mask using Python?

Thanks

```
imgplot = plt.imshow(landmask_ais)

print(landmask_ais.shape)
(180, 216)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

mask = landmask_ais.astype(np.bool_)
struct = ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2, 2)
erode = ndimage.binary_erosion(mask, struct)
edges = mask ^ erode
```

I have found this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742098/border-edge-operations-on-numpy-arrays). edges is an array with the same shape as landmask_ais where edge=TRUE otherwise FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

```
impoprt numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = np.asarray(Image.open('landmark_ais.png'))
img2 = np.full(img.shape, 255, dtype=np.uint8)
h, w = img.shape[:2]
for i in range(h - 1):
    for j in range(w - 1):
        if any(img[i,j,:] != img[i+1,j,:]) or any(img[i,j,:] != img[i,j+1,:]):
            img2[i, j, :] = 0
Image.fromarray(img2)
```

[image]

Very naive approach - I'm sure there's a more robust & efficient way to achieve this w/ opencv.